# Sphinx-quickstart doesn't work

Tags: bash, installation, root, local, python-sphinx

I am trying to install sphinx on a remote machine.

Since I don't have an access to the root, I did this:

```
$bash

$mkdir -p ~/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

$export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

$export PATH=$PATH::~/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

$easy_install -U --prefix=$HOME/local Sphinx
```

But apparently, `$easy_install` doesn't build sphinx-quickstart; when I type

```
$sphinx-quickstart
```

I get the following message:

```
bash: sphinx-quickstart: command not found
```

I tried

```
find $HOME -name sphinx-quickstart
```

and no result was found. However, I can import sphinx inside python:

```
$python
```

And then

```
>>import sphinx
```

works. Any idea why `sphinx-quickstart` doesn't work?

Comment: Does the `PATH` variable contain the subdirectory where the `sphinx-quickstart` is found? -- I see you have updated your `PYTHONPATH` variable but have you updated your `PATH` variable in the same way?

Comment: No, I had not. But now I did, and it is still the same. I typed setenv PATH $PATH\:home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: `$export 
export: Command not found.`

Comment: I aslo typed `$bash` and then `bash-4.3$ export PATH=$PATH:~/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` This works, but doesn't solve the issue with `sphinx-quickstart`

Comment: Try `locate sphinx-quickstart` and `find $HOME -name sphinx-quickstart`.

Comment: `find $HOME -name sphinx-quickstart` doesn't result anything, but still `import sphinx` works in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in this webpage:

> [User (root/sudo free) installation of Python modules.](http://www.astropython.org/tutorials/user-rootsudo-free-installation-of-python-modules7/)

In section **3. Python 2.6+** he mentioned that the command line commands are in

```
~/local/bin
```

Although I had put `~/local/lib/python2.7/siste-packages` in the path, the `~/local/bin` directory was not in the path. So all I did

```
$export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/local/bin
```

and now it works.

I don't know why `find $HOME -name sphinx-quickstart` did not find `sphinx-quickstart`

Comment: Apparently `easy_install` automatically creates the `bin` directory

Answer (score 23):

An alternative way to invoke `sphinx-quickstart` is to explicitly load Sphinx's quickstart module. For Sphinx v1.7+:

```
python -m sphinx.cmd.quickstart
```

For older versions of Sphinx:

```
python -m sphinx.quickstart
```

For example:

```
$ /c/Python35/python -m sphinx.quickstart
Welcome to the Sphinx 1.6.2 quickstart utility.
...
```

Comment: This results in `No module named sphinx.quickstart` on Windows.

Comment: @DiddiZ, it may be `python -m sphinx.cmd.quickstart` on newer versions of Sphinx.

Answer (score 0):

In MacOS (Catalina) and zsh:

I installed sphinx with brew and had the same problem as you.

**Solution**:
Installed it with conda as `conda install sphinx` and now it works for me

```
$ sphinx-quickstart
Welcome to the Sphinx 2.3.0 quickstart utility.
```

[Installation Guide](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/installation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Note, if you're in a virtual environment and using poetry to run

`poetry run py -m sphinx.cmd.quickstart`

where `py` is the python launcher for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Have added an answer for installation on macOS using brew [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74787775/8565339)

> For new users, installing with brew gives the following caveats:
>
> ```
> ==> sphinx-doc
> sphinx-doc is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
> because this formula is mainly used internally by other formulae.
> Users are advised to use `pip` to install sphinx-doc.
>
> If you need to have sphinx-doc first in your PATH, run:
>   echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/sphinx-doc/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
> ```
>
> Running the echo command:
>
> ```
> echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/sphinx-doc/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
> ```
>
> should fix the issue.
>
> Don't miss `source`-ing the .zshrc after the updating it:
>
> ```
> source ~/.zshrc
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I found that running
`python "path to sphinx-quickstart-script.py"`
works. I was using micromamba when I did then and so I had to activate my environment first and then run this in my VS code terminal.