# The 'sphinx-build' command was not found.

Tags: python, windows-10, python-sphinx, chocolatey

This was our processes of installing Sphinx.

```
> choco install python -y -f
> pip install sphinx
```

We know that sphinx installed because of the following output.

```
> pip show sphinx
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: Sphinx
Version: 1.4.3
Summary: Python documentation generator
Home-page: http://sphinx-doc.org/
Author: Georg Brandl
Author-email: georg@python.org
License: BSD
Location: c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\python3\tools\lib\site-packages
```

We also added its install location to our PATH.

```
c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\python3\tools\lib\site-packages
```

Even so, running `sphinx-build` does not work.

```
'sphinx-build' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 34):

I stumbled into that problem too when installed Sphinx using `pip`. The problem was solved using the installation way proposed by [official documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/installation.html):

For Python 3:

```
$ apt-get install python3-sphinx
```

For Python 2:

```
$ apt-get install python-sphinx
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error when I install sphinx from pip in Ubuntu, via a Jenkins pipeline. The Jenkins pipeline fails with `command was not found`, and then it works on a second attempt - probably a path/environment thing? Locally I use Windows, and Sphinx installation works fine.

Comment: This does not work for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS since apt-get packages an outdated version of sphinx that isn't compatible with one installed by pip...

Comment: @H.Scheidl Did you ever find a solution for Jenkins? It works on my machine via docker-compose, but fails in Jenkins.

Comment: Unfortunately, on Ubuntu 22.04, `apt`/`apt-get` installs Sphinx version 4.3.2, whereas the current Sphinx version is 6.1.3.

Comment: The solution from Makiyu (see below), calling python -m sphinx.cmd.build worked for me in my GitLab pipeline on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 25):

For macOS Mojave:

```
$ brew install sphinx-doc
```

upon install brew will notify you to add it to your path, so add the following line to your ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/sphinx-doc/bin:$PATH"
```

after that you can run the sphinx-build command
(you can verify this by for example checking the version)

```
$ sphinx-build --version
sphinx-build 2.0.1
```

Comment: Should be `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/sphinx-doc/bin:$PATH"` for mac M1 ARM computers.

Answer (score 9):

An alternative way to invoke sphinx-build is to explicitly load Sphinx's build module.

For Sphinx v1.7+:

`python -m sphinx.cmd.build`

Here's an example for that I did with my documentation:

```sh
$ python3 -m sphinx.cmd.build -b html docs/ docs/build/
Running Sphinx v4.0.2
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 0 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 1 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] api                                                                      
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] index                                                                     
generating indices... genindex done
writing additional pages... search done
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en)... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded.

The HTML pages are in docs/build.
```

I got the idea of trying to load the module with [this answer, originally for `sphinx-quickstart`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46507300/14614326).
Suprisingly, I succeeded.

Answer (score 5):

We added the wrong directory to the path.

Wrong:

```
c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\python3\tools\lib\site-packages
```

Right:

```
c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\python3\tools\Scripts
```

Comment: Yes!  This was roughly what went wrong for me too.  I had got as far as adding the location found with pip show sphinx, but that pointed me to /home/userid/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages.  The dir I needed to add to my ~/.bashrc was /home/userid/.local/bin/ Once I'd done that python could find the commands I needed to use Sphinx.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows:

Setting python path in `make.bat` fixed the problem for me:

```
set SPHINXBUILD="D:\Python3\Scripts\sphinx-build.exe"
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer!

Answer (score 1):

For macports adding

```
export PATH="/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:$PATH"
```

to $HOME/.bash_profile fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by just installing from `pip` and restarting the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be related to the Python interpreter. At some point in time, some distributions removed

```
 /usr/bin/python
```

`sphinx-build` relied on that. So, may be

```
 sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

may help. But, this needs to be handled with care, since the `PATH` points to this directory and some scripts/programs may then access Python2.7 instead of maybe Python3 from some other place.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a solution by running `python "path to sphinx-build-script.py" source build`. When I did this, I had my micromamba environment active before I ran the command above. This should be the same if you use conda. This basically calls Python to run the sphinx-build-script which requires that you have a source directory and a build directory when the documentation pages will go.