# What is the correct way to configure Sphinx for python3 on Ubuntu VM?

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx, ubuntu-18.04

Just installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on a fresh virtual box this morning and I'm trying to re-invigorate a project I had running on my legacy VBox/Ubuntu environment. I'm stumbling with getting sphinx auto documentation working on the new VBox. Before installing sphinx, I added this to `.bashrc` to execute python3 by default:

```
alias python=python3
```

My method of installing sphinx follows usual procedures:

```
pip3 install Sphinx
```

The trouble is experienced at the first step of the Sphinx tutorial in setting up a project:

```
[user@robot][~]$ sphinx-quickstart
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/sphinx-quickstart", line 14, in <module>
    from sphinx.quickstart import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sphinx.quickstart'
```

Anyone experienced something similar? Given the fresh install environment, I'm anticipating there's something incorrect in my configuration.

Related: [sphinx-build fail - autodoc can't import/find module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324393/sphinx-build-fail-autodoc-cant-import-find-module)

Answer (score 0):

Got things finally working with the following:

```
pip3 uninstall sphinx
sudo su
cd ~
umask 022
pip3 install sphinx
```

Here are a few references that will help the next person:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26941559/9008686

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53117242/9008686

Comment: You should never `sudo` to install Python packages. Always use a virtual environment. `mkdir ~/projects/myproject; cd ~/projects/myproject; python3 -m venv env; env/bin/pip install sphinx`